# Can you help me to get Selenium to click image in Chromedriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however i cant seem to get Selenium to click the "Checkout" button using "element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH".

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL i am practicing on:

https://www.aria.co.uk/myAria/ShoppingBasket

And this is my current code for the clicking:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.aria.co.uk/SuperSpecials/Other+products/ASUS+ROG+Pugio+2+Wireless+Optical+RGB+Gaming+Mouse?productId=72427")
#https://www.aria.co.uk/Products/Components/Graphics+Cards/NVIDIA+GeForce/GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti/Palit+GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti+Dual+8GB+GPU?productId=73054

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "Out of Stock!")))
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("addQuantityButton")
    button.click()

basket = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "basketContent")))
basket.click()

checkout = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/checkoutv2.png.png')]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see your `xpath` is not correct.

Your Xpath should be.

```
//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/checkoutv2.png')]
```

Your code should be.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/checkoutv2.png')]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided contains **hCaptcha**, which is actually responsible to check whether you are a human being or a bot. I guess that it's also the reason, why you can't click any of the items on the page, because Selenium actually is nothing less than a bot.

You first have to pass the test by clicking on the images, which are asked for.